# New compute node with openstack base bundle

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, maas

In my scenario which is deployed with maas and juju, I have a network 10.10.10.0/24 which is used to deploy openstack base churm bundle.
Also the maas and juju are within this network/subnet.

Recently I have added a new compute node to the cluster from a different network segment , 10.10.13.10/24
3 nova computes are in the same network segment but the newly added is from a different subnet.

External network uses flat type and my instances which is created in the new compute node are not accessible via floating/Fixed IP from 10.10.10.0/24 subnet.

What should I do to fix the problem?